# create a logout page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem logging out redirecting a user on a logout page.
I coded the template page with `wp_safe_redirect(wp_logout_url())` but it only shows me an error in logging out. Wordpress is asking me if am i sure to logout or not.
Is it possible to create a logout page on wordpress, when the user goes to this page it automtically log outs the user.

Comment: I don't understand your overall question.  Do you want a user to be able to go to a page that will cause them to logout, or do you want the user to be redirected after they logout, or both?

Comment: Hi Sepster. I want the user to be able to go to a page that will cause them to logout. And i do having a problem here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call `logout` directly:

```
wp_logout();
wp_redirect( wp_login_url() ); // then redirect him to login url
```

Comment: i've tried that code but it redirects me on a page where wordpress ask me that "You are attempting to log out of My Site Do you really want to log out?" .. I dont know why it happens.

Comment: It is not what is states [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_logout)

Comment: oh im sorry mihai lorga.. I thought you use wp_logout_url(). your code did the trick.. thank you so much...

Answer (score 0):

```html
<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url("URL OF login page"); ?>">Logout</a>
```